# Accepting a 'n x n' Matrix in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I've been bugged with this idea for a while.
Accepting an array with spaces is not straight forward in c#. How do we accept a 2d array, whose size is given by the user? I tried this, but something isn't right. Help is much appreciated. Thank You.

```
      Input:
            4
            1 2 3 4
            2 3 4 5
            3 4 5 6
            4 5 6 7
```

Where the first line specifies the value of 'n' in 'n x n'

Well, the code i tried was this. This might look stupid for a few of you :

```
        string input;
        string[] inputArray;
        int[] inputInt;

        int MxM = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //MxM = First Line=n
        int[,] array = new int[MxM, MxM];
        for (int i = 0; i < MxM; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MxM; j++)
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                inputArray = input.Split(' ');
                inputInt = new int[MxM];
                for (int k = 0; k < MxM; k++)
                {
                    inputInt[k] = int.Parse(inputArray[k]);
                    array[i, j] = inputInt[k];
                }
            }
        }
```

Hopefully, the answer for this will also be the answer to output a matrix. Thank You

Comment: How does "something isn't right" express itself?

Comment: I thought the logic was right. And I don't have any build errors. But, the input isn't happening. Cheers

Comment: One thing to note, the inner-most `for-loop` iterates over `k < MxM` incrementing `k` while accessing `inputArray[k]`. You can run into an `IndexOutOfRangeException` depending upon the input from the `input = Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: Also, could you provide  a sample of both the input and the desired output?

Comment: I got that. By the way, let's say, the output is just the matrix itself. Because, all I want is to have a proper 2d array which is accessible for further manipulation. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding what you want correctly:

You would like to take an input `N`, in your example `4`, with that - create a 4 x 4 array. Then for each index in the first dimension, ask the user for input equating to `N` number of integers separated by spaces. Read that input and place it into the array at the proper 2d-index. So with `4` as the first input, the user will be prompted something like:

> ```
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces):
> ```

The user would type in, for example:

> ```
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 1 2 3 4
> ```

And hit enter. Again the user is prompted:

> ```
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 1 2 3 4
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces):
> ```

And so on until:

> ```
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 1 2 3 4
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 2 3 4 5
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 3 4 5 6
> Please input 4 integers(separated by spaces): 4 5 6 7
> ```

You could probably use something like the following in this case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the size of the matrix:");
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value provided for the size was not a proper integer value.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to quit...");
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) { }
            return;
        }

        int[,] matrix = new int[size, size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            bool complete = false;
            while (!complete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] - Please input {1} integers(separated by spaces):", i, size));
                string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                if (input.Count() != size)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid, try again...");
                    continue;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                {
                    if (!int.TryParse(input[j], out matrix[i, j]))
                    {
                        complete = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("The input was invalid, try again...");
                        break;
                    }
                    complete = true;
                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Output: \n");
        WriteMatrix(matrix, size);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void WriteMatrix(int[,] matrix, int size)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
                line += string.Format("{0} ", matrix[i, j]);
            output += string.Format("{0}\n", line.Trim());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

}
```

The code above should be mostly safe against the user typing invalid values, but you could probably spend some time to clean it up or enhance it some more. The basic idea is there.

Comment: Great work! Although I don't want it to be too much user friendly, this is the safest it can get! Thanks for sharing. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MxM; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < MxM; j++)
    array[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MxM; i++)
{
  inputArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
  for (int j = 0; j < MxM; j++)
    array[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(inputArray[j]);
}
```

which, of course, could fail if you don't enter in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use code like this:

> Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(str => Convert.ToInt32(str)).ToArray()

to get an int array out of the line.

I think you understood the idea.

Comment: I understood that. its a replacement for the 6 lines of code inside the two for loops. But it doesn't make my code any successful. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[,] MatrixConstructor()
{
    int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] matrix = new int[N, N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        String[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            matrix[i,j] = Convert.ToInt32(line[j]);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

This conforms to your input.